# DrEdit PHP and Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am using DrEdit PHP sdk library. Using their own output editor I am trying to create a file with mimetype `application/vnd.google-apps.kix`

It says it saved but when I try to open it from the Drive itself it returns an error:

> Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested does not exist.
>   Make sure that you have the correct URL and that the owner of the document hasn't deleted it.

I kept DrEdits' own config apart from ClientId, Secret etc. and changed the mime/type.

Anyone can tell me what the problem can be please?

Thanks

Comment: Does the request succeed? How are you trying to access the file after creating it? Check your alternativeLink in the response.

Comment: Yeah it says that file has been created as it IS shown on Google Drive as stated above ! There seems to be something bad in the link though as it is quiet short compared to the real Google Doc created in the Google Drive ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MIME-type is used by Google Documents (word processor).

Unfortunately you can't create Google native documents directly using the Google Drive SDK.
The only way to create a native Google document is to upload a document of one of the supported import formats (PDF, Word, RTF...) and to set the [`convert` URL parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) to `true` this will convert the document into one of the native Google Docs formats.

Comment: Oh that seems right, that actually works ! But I've run in another issue .... I would like to change output_editor.php to cater for bold, italics etc... How should the data be sent when sending request to google? Thanks !